# Prime number and fraction problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$p$ is a prime number and $m$ is a whole number, how many pairs of $(p,m)$ exist such that $\frac{m^3-pm+1}{m^2 + pm + 2}$ is a prime number?

My attempt: Obviously the denominator should be able to divide numerator, but I don't know how to proceed from there or how to manipulate the fraction where the answer should be more obvious.

Comment: Note, if $p$ is odd, then the denominator $m^2+pm+2$ is even while the numerator $m^3-pm+1$ is odd.  (The has nothing to do with $p$ being prime, it's true of *all* odd numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

As @Barry Cipra mentioned, $p$ can't be odd, since in that case the numerator is odd and the denomminator is even, so the quotient will not be an integer.

So, we are left with the case $p=2$, we have $\frac{m^3-2m+1}{m^2+2m+2}\in\mathbb{Z}$.

By long division(or any other method you know to divide polynomials), you have that $m^3-2m+1=(m^2+2m+2)(m-2)+5$.

Hence, $(m-2)+\frac{5}{m^2+2m+2}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Which implies that $m^2+2m+2$ divides $5$. There are only few options here

$m^2+2m+2=(m+1)^2+1=1$, where you get the solution $m=-1$ or $m^2+2m+2=(m+1)^2+1=5$, where you get the solutions $m=1$, $m=-3$.

So the only solutions are $(p,m)=\{(2,-1);(2,1);(2,-3)\}$